# specifics replace substring in string with php function

Tags: php, preg-replace, replaceall

in the text, i would like to replace the **div** tag **li**. But not everyone just certain well defined. In this case, those that have id that begins "tab-*"
I need something using PHP functions easily from text:

```
<div id="tab-141285" class="my-class">                         
  <div class="my-subclass">              
    <div>                     
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer                 
    </div>             
  </div>                 
</div>                   
<div id="tab-85429"  class="my-class">                                  
  <div class="my-subclass">              
    <div>                      
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer                  
    </div>             
  </div>                 
</div>
```

get this text

```
<li id="tab-141285" class="my-class">                          
  <div class="my-subclass">              
    <div>                     
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer                 
    </div>             
  </div>                 
</li>                
<li id="tab-85429"  class="my-class">                                   
  <div class="my-subclass">              
    <div>                      
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer                  
    </div>             
  </div>                 
</li>
```

Can you advise me?

Thank you

Comment: Where's the code you've tried? I see nothing `preg_replace` related.

Comment: I would advise against a pritive substring replacement approach. Though this is possible it carries a certain risk that things break the moment the markup is not implemented exactly as expected. Instead you should take a look at a php based DOM parser and manipulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are not adequate for parsing HTML. Any regex you try to use will be fragile. I suggest using the [DOM extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for this instead.

The idea is to:

1. Find all the `<div>` elements that have an `id` attribute that begins with `"tab-"` using the [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) [query](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) `//div[starts-with(@id, "tab-")]`
2. [Create](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) a new `<li>` element for each of them.
3. Move all the `<div>`'s attributes and child nodes to the new `<li>` element.
4. Replace the old `<div>` with the new `<li>`.

Because your string doesn't have a root element, we'll do a little dance before and after to put it in one then rebuild it.

---

#### Example:

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<div id="tab-141285" class="my-class">
  <div class="my-subclass">
    <div>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="tab-85429"  class="my-class">
  <div class="my-subclass">
    <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("<div>$html</div>", LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->query('//div[starts-with(@id, "tab-")]');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $li = $dom->createElement('li');

    while ($node->attributes->length) {
        $li->setAttributeNode($node->attributes->item(0));
    }
    while ($node->firstChild) {
        $li->appendChild($node->firstChild);
    }

    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($li, $node);
}

$html = '';
foreach ($dom->documentElement->childNodes as $node) {
    $html .= $dom->saveHTML($node);
}

echo $html;
```

---

#### Output:

```
<li id="tab-141285" class="my-class">
  <div class="my-subclass">
    <div>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
<li id="tab-85429" class="my-class">
  <div class="my-subclass">
    <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you, 

This is what I wanted. I was just there at the end instead of added
 
echo $html; 

echo preg_replace ('/(<\/?body>)|(<\/?html>)/i', '', $ html);

Comment: Hi,
after all I still have one question. Why is

**$dom->loadHTML("<div>$html</div>", LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);**

and not


**$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);**

Answer (score 0):

use domdocument xml component of php just load the string in domdocument object and search for element then get its attribute and check its id and compare using preg_replace and remove if it met your condition

Comment: How it should look like?